Change the increment in Svelte's #each logic block
Is it possible to change the increment in the #each logic block?
Using a for loop, it's simple to change the increment to 2, for example:
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i+=2) { 

I get an error when trying to do the same within Svelte's #each block.

It's not possible.
You could either (reactively if necessary) create a new array from the existing one or skip indices you don't want to display via #if.
{#each items as item, i}
  {#if i % 2 == 0}
     <!-- every second item -->
  {/if}
{/each}


With {#each} in Svelte, you must pass it a sequence with the values you want to iterate over. The sequence you want can for example be generated using this function:
const arrayRange = (start, stop, step) =>
    Array.from(
        { length: (stop - start) / step + 1 },
        (value, index) => start + index * step
    );

Then you can use it like this:
{#each arrayRange(0, items.length, 2) as i}
   <div>{i}</div>
{/each}


That's a nice function. It's slightly different than my use case though for which I've already come up with a solution. Each 2 items in my array are to be displayed in the parent component (which is the component within the #each block) and then I don't wont to duplicate, so need to skip.

@code_sanchu: This function would work as well, you would just have to get the item via the respective index, e.g. via {@const item = items[i]} within the #each. Or rewrite the function to take an array and return the items directly.
